# Transform Xml content in a table

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have one table with a field that contains a XML content and I would to transform this XML content in a table where each tag would be a column.
Does Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the tags in advance, but you can then use XMLTABLE for this, eg if table table_with_employee_xml has a column xml_col, as per below

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <empno>7369</empno>
    <ename>SMITH</ename>
    <job>CLERK</job>
    <hiredate>17-DEC-1980</hiredate>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>7499</empno>
    <ename>ALLEN</ename>
    <job>SALESMAN</job>
    <hiredate>20-FEB-1981</hiredate>
  </employee>
  ...
  ...

select x.*
from   table_with_employee_xml e,
       xmltable('/employees/employee'
         passing e.xml_col
         columns 
           empno     varchar2(4)  path 'empno',
           ename     varchar2(10) path 'ename',
           job       varchar2(9)  path 'job',
           hiredate  varchar2(11) path 'hiredate'
         ) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE EDMU_XML (
  id        NUMBER,
  xml_data  XMLTYPE
);


insert into EDMU_XML values (1,'<employees>
  <employee>
    <empno>1</empno>
    <ename>EDMU1</ename>
    <job>SALESMAN</job>\
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>2</empno>
    <ename>EDMU2</ename>
    <job>MANAGER</job>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>3</empno>
    <ename>EDMU3</ename>
    <job>MANAGER</job>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <empno>4</empno>
    <ename>EDMU4</ename>
    <job>ANALYST</job>
  </employee>
</employees>');


CREATE TABLE EDMU_NORMAL AS
SELECT xt.*
FROM   EDMU_XML x,
       XMLTABLE('/employees/employee'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           empno     VARCHAR2(4)  PATH 'empno',
           ename     VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'ename',
           job       VARCHAR2(9)  PATH 'job'
         ) xt;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7cbf912a08aac5c70f0c25862094bbfa)